# Finding a special solution in a solution set over F2

Tags: linear-programming

Given a solution set of a linear system of the following form
$$
\{ \begin{bmatrix}
           x_{1} \\
           \vdots \\
           x_{n}
         \end{bmatrix} = \vec{v_1} * x_1 + \dots + \vec{v_n} * x_n \} 
$$
in $ \mathbb{Z}_{2}$. 
If $ x_i $ ($1 \leq i \leq n$) isn't a free variable, $\vec{v_i} = \vec{0}$.

I want to find a solution to the solution set where the following is true
$$
x_1 + \dots + x_n = k + 1
$$
in $ \mathbb{Z}$ (not in $ \mathbb{Z}_{2}$) for k $\in \mathbb{N}$.

That the solution set is in $ \mathbb{Z}_{2}$ means the linear system was in $ \mathbb{Z}_{2}$ too and all variables will either be 0 or 1 meaning the vector addition is also in $ \mathbb{Z}_{2}$.

The following might help with the problem (I will also go into programming opportunities):

- The max. amount of "enabled" vectors is $k+1$. This is because for each enabled vector there will be one free variable enabled.
- You can reduce the problem to
  $$
  m_1x_1 + \dots + m_nx_n \equiv_2 k+1
  $$
  but I don't know how to go on.
- You could do a depth-first search but its runtime would increase really quickly.
- There might be a possibility that you can do [backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking) s.t. you do DFS but skip sub-trees that can not be a valid solution.
- There might be an linear programming approach

I'm really interested in solving this problem and am hoping for some kind help.

Comment: I don't understand the question (aside from the fact that you use F2 in the title and $\mathbb Z_2$ in the body; I assume they both refer to the finite field with 2 elements).  What is the linear system that you are trying to solve?  Is it the vector equation in curly braces?  Are the $\vec v_i$ the standard basis vectors, or fixed but unspecified vectors?  How do we know whether or not a given $x_i$ is a free variable, and, if it is not, then what does it mean for it to appear on the left-hand side of the equation?

Comment: Yes, Z_2 and F2 mean the same thing here. The first linear system to solve is or the form $ A \vec{x} = \vec{0} $. The provide vector equation is the solution set to the first linear system and the vectors are fixed but unspecified. The second linear equation is the $x_1, \dots , x_n = k+1$ one. This one is exposed to be solved given the solution set (in curly brackets) of the First linear system.

Answer (score 0):

This is tantamount to standard and difficult problem (known to be NP-complete)
in coding theory.  The solution set is a coset of a linear binary code;
the integer sum of coordinates, $x_1 + \cdots + x_n$,  is the Hamming weight of $\vec x$.
So in effect you're asking for a codeword at given distance from a fixed vector.  If we could do this efficiently then we could solve both the
"shortest codeword" and "nearest codeword" problems.

Comment: Do you mean the problem is to find a vector with a Hamming weight of k + 1 in the vector space? Are there any approaching algorithms or good algorithms for small values (n <= 200, k = 11)?